# Xamarin forms can't resize the image inside list view

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SaleProperties}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                               HeightRequest="500"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

i'm trying to change the size of my image but it can't exceed this size
[image]

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: set the RowSize on the ListView and/or specify a height for the StackLayout

Comment: it worked . ty man